# How do I SELECT username FROM 'myTable' WHERE username = (get * usernames from a different table)

Tags: mysql, database

What I'm trying to do is get the `usernames` and `picURLs` from `table1` WHERE usernames = all the usernames from this query (`SELECT usernames FROM table2`).

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE USERNAMES IN (SELECT USERNAMES FROM TABLE2)`

Comment: Use an `inner join`...

Comment: Also, please don't add unneccessary tags to a question unless they are relevant to the content. This is neither related to Java nor PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. I did some searching online before hand but i wasn't quite sure how to ask it so i didn't have much success. Thank you for the answers and i apologise for my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
  usernames,
  picURLs
FROM 
  table1 INNER JOIN
  table2 ON table2.usernames = table1.usernames
```

The [`inner join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) is used to join both tables together, using the condition `table2.usernames = table1.usernames`.

I will recommend reading more about `SQL Joins` and then you will be comfortable to perform such queries.

Note: From question is not clear if the problem is with the `SQL` syntax, or if is on how to connect the database with your code, and perform `SQL`. If so, please update your question.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comment from a user (and is worth adding it here just for the reference) you can also use the following query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table1
WHERE 
  usernames IN (SELECT usernames FROM table2)
```

More information about the `SQL Joins` have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).